# jQuery/JavaScript - auto cut & format paragraphs depending on the browser's window height and width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let say I have a very long page of content consisting of multiple paragraphs which cannot be
displayed in a single browser window with vertical scrollbar

```
<p>...very long sentence ...</p>
<p>...very long sentence ...</p>
<p>...very long sentence ...</p>
<p>...very long sentence ...</p>
```

So I want to cut the paragraphs and format them into multiple pages, e.g.

```
<!-- page 1 -->
<p>...very long sentence ...</p>
<p>...very long </p><!-- the ending p tag is automatic inserted since the following text cannot be displayed -->

<!-- page 2 -->
<p>sentence ...</p>
<p>...very long sentence ...</p>
<p>...very long sentence ...</p>
```

Are there any existing scripts for this purpose?

In the extreme case the paragraph might contain image, so each line might be variying in height.

Comment: What do you mean by Page? You mean seperate HTML pages which you want to navigate using pagination?

Comment: If you'r just looking for some kind of front end pagination then jquery plugins available such as this one http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/11/17/jpaginate-a-fancy-jquery-pagination-plugin/

Comment: @Yoga: Added a working demo in my answer below. Hope it is the one your are looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

Someone has created show/hide functionality with jQuery.

This may help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Example: Show more, less using jQuery</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        a.moreText
        {
            color: blue;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding-left: 5px;
            padding-right: 10px;
        }

        a.lessText
        {
            cursor: pointer;
            color: blue;
            display: none;
            padding-left: 5px;
            padding-right: 10px;
        }

        span.secondHalf
        {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("p").each(function () {
                SetMoreLess(this, 350, 20, " ... more", " ... less");
            });

            $("a.moreText").click(function () {
                $(this).hide();
                var pTag = $(this).parents("p.summary");

                $(pTag).find("a.lessText").show();
                $(pTag).find("span.secondHalf").show();
            });

            $("a.lessText").click(function () {
                $(this).hide();
                var pTag = $(this).parents("p.summary");

                $(pTag).find("a.moreText").show();
                $(pTag).find("span.secondHalf").hide();
            });
        });

        function SetMoreLess(para, thrLength, tolerance, moreText, lessText) {
            var alltext = $(para).html().trim();

            $(para).addClass("summary");        // this class is added to identify the p tag, when more/less links are clicked

            if (alltext.length + tolerance < thrLength) {
                return;
            }
            else {
                var firstHalf = alltext.substring(0, thrLength);
                var secondHalf = alltext.substring(thrLength, alltext.length);

                var firstHalfSpan = '<span class="firstHalf">' + firstHalf + '</span>';
                var secondHalfSpan = '<span class="secondHalf">' + secondHalf + '</span>';
                var moreTextA = '<a class="moreText">' + moreText + '</a>';
                var lessTextA = '<a class="lessText">' + lessText + '</a>';

                var newHtml = firstHalfSpan + moreTextA + secondHalfSpan + lessTextA;

                $(para).html(newHtml);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="lipsum">

        <p>
            Integer consectetur, dui ut lobortis aliquet, leo est ullamcorper augue, id blandit
            metus libero eu leo. Pellentesque dui sapien, tempus ultricies ultricies nec, molestie
            at eros. Integer facilisis luctus libero quis accumsan. Suspendisse eu velit ac
            erat iaculis pellentesque vel mollis est. Cras ac erat vulputate augue tincidunt
            euismod a eu diam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
            fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam sed arcu lorem. Cras porta dui in lorem tempor dapibus.
            Ut magna metus, tincidunt et sodales pretium, aliquam ac ligula. Etiam at enim id
            enim rhoncus scelerisque. Fusce porta, arcu non malesuada consequat, massa lectus
            feugiat diam, aliquam convallis neque mauris eu urna. Nulla pellentesque eleifend
            lectus, vel sodales leo consequat vestibulum. Sed elementum, lorem ac mollis mattis,
            purus dolor interdum neque, ac rutrum nisl elit eu arcu. Curabitur risus arcu, suscipit
            dignissim hendrerit at, luctus nec mauris. Pellentesque accumsan euismod sem nec
            feugiat. Nullam faucibus gravida elit, nec facilisis lorem ullamcorper nec.
        </p>
        <p>
            Vestibulum tincidunt lacus sit amet justo blandit vehicula. In pretium sem quis
            ligula ultricies eget sodales velit mollis. Phasellus facilisis varius enim, non
            rutrum nulla scelerisque eu. Curabitur posuere quam eget dui dignissim sed placerat
            ante tincidunt. Suspendisse faucibus vulputate est quis feugiat. Nulla nec ante
            a enim molestie consectetur. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec tincidunt lacinia
            pellentesque. Integer hendrerit ligula non nibh posuere pretium. Sed tincidunt tincidunt
            lectus, non consectetur est iaculis sit amet. Morbi vel lobortis ligula. Sed scelerisque
            varius interdum. In sollicitudin lorem et mauris luctus venenatis commodo nunc venenatis.
            Praesent vitae justo nisl.
        </p>
        <p>
            Nulla posuere ante vel quam dapibus fringilla. In elementum mi interdum nisl vehicula
            eu iaculis felis pretium. Ut id massa eget turpis gravida luctus et non nunc. Etiam
            viverra suscipit mauris quis scelerisque. Vestibulum tempor neque nisl, nec aliquam
            nibh. Quisque cursus faucibus libero sit amet placerat. Nulla id blandit ligula.
            Nullam aliquam dui at justo facilisis accumsan. Morbi vel arcu id mi mollis vestibulum.
            Praesent imperdiet, lectus eget adipiscing lobortis, urna enim vulputate lorem,
            et bibendum turpis arcu quis ligula. Donec ultricies sollicitudin imperdiet. Mauris
            a augue nulla. Donec sagittis est magna, sed scelerisque magna. Nam tincidunt, felis
            quis luctus sodales, orci ligula consequat massa, a pulvinar leo urna id dui. In
            sit amet augue est, et tincidunt metus. Quisque pellentesque, felis vel semper ullamcorper,
            leo nulla eleifend nunc, et suscipit massa tellus non tellus.
        </p>
        <p>
            Etiam accumsan, diam semper mattis tempus, sapien erat cursus dui, venenatis convallis
            metus lectus at arcu. Duis eget dolor nec metus laoreet aliquam. Nulla eu viverra
            massa. Vestibulum id urna ante, at aliquam augue. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et
            magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nulla risus felis, convallis
            at sagittis nec, fringilla in lacus. Integer at fermentum enim. Nullam lacinia eleifend
            nisi, laoreet porta nunc elementum ut. Nulla facilisi.
        </p>
        <p>
            Fusce id orci dui. In nec tempor nulla. Fusce commodo cursus orci in feugiat. Fusce
            porttitor nulla sit amet arcu tempor nec viverra risus tempor. Pellentesque felis
            lectus, pellentesque dignissim interdum sed, aliquam eu urna. In molestie leo vel
            massa dapibus imperdiet. Ut risus odio, rutrum eu congue sit amet, pellentesque
            quis urna. Duis tempor magna eu nisl volutpat eget pulvinar ante rutrum. Morbi quis
            dolor lorem, sit amet pellentesque mauris. Nunc tellus tellus, consequat a pharetra
            eu, cursus eu dolor. Aliquam non dolor mauris. Vestibulum vel purus eu massa sollicitudin
            sollicitudin vel in mauris. Proin tristique, mi sed tempus facilisis, odio elit
            faucibus turpis, sed aliquam risus elit in urna.
        </p>
        <p>
            Suspendisse et libero tincidunt mauris pharetra hendrerit at ac nisl. Cras mauris
            ante, sodales at scelerisque in, ullamcorper sed ipsum. Praesent est erat, mollis
            eget ullamcorper quis, mattis ac nisi. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
            et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam vulputate, lacus non iaculis
            euismod, urna eros fringilla leo, a faucibus enim metus sed nibh. Etiam sagittis
            sodales porttitor. Aliquam consequat lacus sed enim scelerisque vel malesuada sapien
            viverra. Nulla massa metus, dignissim at consectetur sed, elementum nec massa. Phasellus
            cursus, odio sagittis molestie aliquam, est mi volutpat nibh, nec ullamcorper lacus
            mi sit amet nulla. Vivamus pellentesque, nulla ut pretium pretium, massa justo malesuada
            nibh, a adipiscing diam enim eget elit. Phasellus nec sapien id elit lobortis sodales
            vel ut neque. Sed ultricies tincidunt hendrerit. Vestibulum at velit diam, in sollicitudin
            eros. Cras tincidunt tincidunt orci, id hendrerit lorem porttitor a.
        </p>

        <p>
            Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus
            mus. Ut tortor quam, sodales a egestas ac, consectetur vitae eros. Suspendisse sit
            amet libero ac magna sagittis tincidunt. Quisque a risus orci. Etiam nec velit tortor,
            sed interdum nulla. Mauris nec lorem tortor, a dapibus mi. Sed posuere tempor magna
            vitae consequat.
        </p>
        <p>
            Nam ornare massa a velit congue ut con</p>
        <p>
            Nulla sed magna sed lectus imperdiet sagittis sed at nunc. Duis ornare tortor in
            eros rhoncus quis tempor justo congue. Proin ut suscipit augue. Sed consectetur
            arcu eget purus condimentum venenatis. Pellentesque dui orci, malesuada ut fringilla
            et, tincidunt quis est. Pellentesque ipsum metus, pulvinar sit amet accumsan non,
            imperdiet non enim. Donec leo lorem, pharetra at eleifend id, malesuada ut enim.
            Proin ligula risus, pretium eget adipiscing a, sagittis et tellus. Duis dictum tristique
            pretium. Sed mattis neque vitae augue aliquet dictum. Proin ut tempus velit. Donec
            tincidunt hendrerit risus, vel imperdiet libero interdum ut. Phasellus rutrum sem
            a urna semper et fermentum purus mattis. Aliquam euismod tempor dapibus. Maecenas
            ultrices magna at ligula ultrices at accumsan erat sagittis. Ut neque ante, scelerisque
            ut laoreet egestas, tempus ut erat.
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In case of paragraph with image and other html tags use below logic:

```
<div style="height:500px;overflow:hidden" id="blah">
Hello Hello Hello.Hello Hello Hello.Hello Hello Hello.Hello Hello Hello.Hello Hello Hello.Hello Hello Hello.Hello Hello Hello.Hello Hello Hello.Hello Hello Hello.Hello Hello Hello.Hello Hello Hello.Hello Hello Hello.Hello Hello Hello.
</div>
<a href="#" id="showmore">Show more</a>
<script>
$("#showmore").live('click', function() {
   $("#blah").css('height','1000px');

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

**Edited:** (*Demo Link Updated*)

See this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/bKhcy/)

**By using the below code you can paginate limitless paragraphs as according to your need.**

**jQuery:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        //how much items per page to show
        var show_per_page = 5; 
        //getting the amount of elements inside content div
        var number_of_items = $('#content').children().size();
        //calculate the number of pages we are going to have
        var number_of_pages = Math.ceil(number_of_items/show_per_page);

        //set the value of our hidden input fields
        $('#current_page').val(0);
        $('#show_per_page').val(show_per_page);

        //now when we got all we need for the navigation let's make it '

        /* 
        what are we going to have in the navigation?
            - link to previous page
            - links to specific pages
            - link to next page
        */
        var navigation_html = '<a class="previous_link" href="javascript:previous();">Prev</a>';
        var current_link = 0;
        while(number_of_pages > current_link){
            navigation_html += '<a class="page_link" href="javascript:go_to_page(' + current_link +')" longdesc="' + current_link +'">'+ (current_link + 1) +'</a>';
            current_link++;
        }
        navigation_html += '<a class="next_link" href="javascript:next();">Next</a>';

        $('#page_navigation').html(navigation_html);

        //add active_page class to the first page link
        $('#page_navigation .page_link:first').addClass('active_page');

        //hide all the elements inside content div
        $('#content').children().css('display', 'none');

        //and show the first n (show_per_page) elements
        $('#content').children().slice(0, show_per_page).css('display', 'block');

    });​

    function previous(){

        new_page = parseInt($('#current_page').val()) - 1;
        //if there is an item before the current active link run the function
        if($('.active_page').prev('.page_link').length==true){
            go_to_page(new_page);
        }

    }

    function next(){
        new_page = parseInt($('#current_page').val()) + 1;
        //if there is an item after the current active link run the function
        if($('.active_page').next('.page_link').length==true){
            go_to_page(new_page);
        }

    }
    function go_to_page(page_num){
        //get the number of items shown per page
        var show_per_page = parseInt($('#show_per_page').val());

        //get the element number where to start the slice from
        start_from = page_num * show_per_page;

        //get the element number where to end the slice
        end_on = start_from + show_per_page;

        //hide all children elements of content div, get specific items and show them
        $('#content').children().css('display', 'none').slice(start_from, end_on).css('display', 'block');

        /*get the page link that has longdesc attribute of the current page and add active_page class to it
        and remove that class from previously active page link*/
        $('.page_link[longdesc=' + page_num +']').addClass('active_page').siblings('.active_page').removeClass('active_page');

        //update the current page input field
        $('#current_page').val(page_num);
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
    <!-- the input fields that will hold the variables we will use -->
    <input type='hidden' id='current_page' />
    <input type='hidden' id='show_per_page' />

    <!-- Content div. The child elements will be used for paginating(they don't have to be all the same,
        you can use divs, paragraphs, spans, or whatever you like mixed together). '-->
    <div id='content'>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p>Vestibulum consectetur ipsum sit amet urna euismod imperdiet aliquam urna laoreet.</p>
        <p>and so on....</p>
    </div>

    <!-- An empty div which will be populated using jQuery -->
    <div id='page_navigation'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your demo, you answer is close, except I need a fixed height, e.g. when the width is narrower, I want the extra text goes into next page instead of wrapping into a new row.

Comment: Hi, Have tried the updated demo, actually I am looking at the absolute height of a page, not absolute number of P tags per page. If a page width get narrower, a P tag might need to split into two in order to accommodate the absolute height..

Answer (score 2):

A while ago, I created [pagify](https://gist.github.com/3516393), a jQuery plugin to do just that. It detects page height by splitting elements into words and incrementally adding the words until the height reaches a specified height. I've given it some CSS to make it look like pages in the demo below, but you can style it to use 100% width and height. You can call it simply with `$('body').pagify(options);` The default options are as follows

```
{
    'pageTag' : 'div', // the tag which surrounds each page
    'pageClass': 'page', // the class of the page tag
    'innerClass': 'page-inner', // the class of the inner page element
    'pageSize': 'A4', // a class added to the page so that the size can be defined by css
    'pageSizeClassPrefix': 'page-', // the prefix to the above class
    'pageOrientation': 'portrait', // not yet used, but could be used to flip width and height
    'splitElementClass': 'split-element' // elements which have been split across two pages are given this class
};
```

So to use 100% width and height:

```
html, body, page-screen-size {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and

```
$('body').pagify({
    pageSize : 'screen-size'
});
```

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/nathan/nfHHE/

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand this is very similar to the way an online reader works, where content is formatted into different pages or slides and it doesn't matter what the content inside it is, as this will adapt to its container.

In order to achieve your goal, I'd recommend CSS3 Multi-column layout (see http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-css3-multicol-20010118/)

**CSS**

```
#your-container 
{ 
  width: 90%; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  overflow: hidden; //Hide overflowing content
  padding: 20px 0; 
}

#div-inside-container //For padding and columns display purposes
{ 
  position: relative; 

  -moz-column-count: 1; 
  -webkit-column-count: 1; 
  column-count: 1; 

  -moz-column-width: 50em; 
  -webkit-column-width: 50em; 
  column-width: 50em; 

  -webkit-column-gap: 0; 
  -moz-column-gap: 0; 
  column-gap: 0; 
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(window).resize(function() {

    //Resize container
    $(div_content).height(Dimensions.TellMeHeight() - padding);

});
```

**See example and code**: http://jsfiddle.net/GLbXX/1/

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery `accordion` control, if you have multiple paragaraphs than you should divide then in accordion, it will improve the readabilty and look of your page

[Read more from here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/)

Answer (score 0):

The Financial Times has developed a JavaScript solution for multi-column layout with special focus on complicated (i.e. newspaper-like) cases, [FTColumnFlow](https://github.com/ftlabs/ftcolumnflow).

If you set a container to the width of one column and do then some pagination, i.e. via jQuery UI tabs, this might be a solution, that caters most difficult cases.

Comment: Note: no compatibility with IE9 and below (but it has a lot of features)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code help you. Maybe there is some cases which are omitted or you can find a better alhorithm or you can optimize it. It is just a way to lead you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var current_page_height = $(window).innerHeight() - $("div.pagination").innerHeight();

    function createPages(page_height){
        var current_page_height = 0;
        var pages = [];

        var current_page = [];
        var cpt_page = 0;

        $("div.content").children().each(function(index, element){
            var el = $(element);
            el.hide();

            if(current_page_height + el.innerHeight() > page_height){
                var height_over = (current_page_height+el.innerHeight()) - page_height;
                var line_height_el = el.css("line-height").replace("px","")

                if( line_height_el < height_over && el.find("img").length == 0){
                    var number_line_to_remove = Math.round(height_over/line_height_el);
                    var number_line = el.innerHeight() / line_height_el;
                    var char_by_line = Math.floor(el.html().length / number_line);
                    var content_el = el.html();
                    var pointer_substr = (number_line - number_line_to_remove) * char_by_line;

                    while(content_el.charAt(pointer_substr) != " " && pointer_substr > 0){
                        pointer_substr--;
                    }

                    var new_element = $("<p>" + content_el.substr( pointer_substr, content_el.length-1) + "</p>");
                    el.html( content_el.substr(0, pointer_substr+1));
                    current_page.push(el);
                    el.after(new_element);
                    el = new_element;
                    el.hide();
                }

                pages[cpt_page] = current_page;
                current_page_height = 0;
                current_page = [];
                cpt_page++;
            }
            current_page.push( el );
            current_page_height += el.innerHeight();
        });

        if(current_page.length > 0){
            pages[cpt_page] = current_page;
        }

        return pages;
    }

    function displayPage(page_to_display){
        if( page_to_display >= 0 && page_to_display < pages.length){
            $(pages[page_to_display]).each(function(index, element){
                element.show();
            });

            $(pages[$("span.page").html()]).each(function(index,element){
                element.hide();
            });
            $("span.page").html(page_to_display);
        }
    }

    var pages = createPages(current_page_height);
    displayPage(0);

    $("span.next").click(function(){
       var page = new Number($("span.page").html());
       displayPage( page+1 );
    });

    $("span.prev").click(function(){
       var page = new Number($("span.page").html());
       displayPage( page-1 );
    });

});
```

You can find an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/charlesjourdan/sfKwM/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Sugar.js has a great .truncate() function that crops text to your specifications

http://sugarjs.com/api/String/truncate

Answer (score 0):

try this jquery plugin 
[jqPagination](http://beneverard.github.com/jqPagination/) or [jPaginate](http://tympanus.net/jPaginate/)

Answer (score -2):

have a look at **:before** and **:after** pseudo-elements in CSS (sorry, I can't be more specific, I'm still on the discovery path myself)